# How to create an Access Token inside Keycloak SPI (custom event listener) with grant_type `client_credentials`

Tags: token, keycloak, event-listener, keycloak-spi

There is a need to have an **access token** in custom SPI to call the other microservices in the system.

It is possible to have **client_id** and **client_secret**.

Can you suggest any variants?

Comment: I'm not sure SPI abbreviation means the same in your question and in the tag.

Comment: Did you find any luck with this?

Comment: @CuriousMind I didn't

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrKazimirov I ended up creating HTTP Client, which invokes Keycloak token issuer URL from SPI itself.